# Application badge number updates parse swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, badge

I have an app implementing push notifications with parse.

I am having some issues clearing the badge icon when a user opens up the app.

I have the following line of code in my appDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions and in the app didBecomeActive:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
```

This works temporarily in that if I have a badge number of 18 and then I take my app out of the background via launching it, I then press the home button and I can see the app badge number was cleared and there is no longer a red icon a number in it for my app, as expected.

But then if I receive a new notification, the app badge does not read 1 as expected but instead 1 is added to the previous badge number that had been cleared and is now 19.

How can I handle this?

My app sends push notifications with the following data:

```
var data = [ "title": "xxx",
             "alert": message, 
             "badge" : "Increment",
             "sound" : "default"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that the you are not clearing the badge number saved in Parse's `PFInstallation`.

Update the badge number using `PFInstallation` rather than directly modifying it using `UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0`

`PFInstallation` will automatically take care of clearing the badge icon as well as updating the badge number in Parse's backend.

Add the following to the app delegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and also to `applicationDidBecomeActive`

```
if (PFInstallation.currentInstallation().badge != 0) {
    PFInstallation.currentInstallation().badge = 0
    PFInstallation.currentInstallation().saveInBackground()
}
```

You may also want to add the following to `applicationDidBecomeActive`

```
// Clears out all notifications from Notification Center
UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelAllLocalNotifications()
```

Comment: thank you it worked. And thanks for the tip on the notification center also.